# ODBC connect from R to Access DB .accdb file on Network Drive

Tags: r, ms-access, odbc

I have a .accdb Access DB file on a network drive that I have mapped to the Z:/ drive on my local machine.  Can you connect ODBC to this?

This is the code to create the ODBC (`usrAccessPath` is the string variable containing the file path):

```
connAccessDB <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=",usrAccessDBPath))
```

This file path works:

```
C:/Users/boswelpa/Desktop/Projects/Absenteeism/Absenteeism Data.accdb
```

But this file path (mapped network drive) does not work:

```
Z:/SSG Reporting Team/For Thomas/Absenteeism Data.accdb
```

Same code, just different file paths.

Comment: Yes, you can. Look into RODBC.

Comment: I am currently using RODBC.  It's an AccessDB file, so I'm connecting straight through the file path.  That is, I haven't created an ODBC connection in the Windows ODBC manager.  I tried swapping out the original file path I was using with the new mapped network drive file path and it doesn't connect.

Comment: This is the error I receive, implying that I cannot connect to an external server:

1: In odbcDriverConnect(paste0("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=",  :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state HY024, code -1023, message [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] '(unknown)' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

Comment: Please show us full, attempted code.

Comment: I edited my question and added the code.  Thank you

Comment: You may not have effectively mapped the drive. Can you open database directly from Z drive? In command window, check network paths with command `net use`. Consider referencing the full UNC path (no mapped letters).

Comment: Alright the UNC path works!!!  Thank you.  If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, ODBC calls to MS Access databases such as R with RODBC accepts both local hard disk or network paths (i.e., Universal Naming Convention (UNC)), provided they follow the Windows [file name rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). Of course, be sure to escape backslashes in R by doubling the character:

Hence, the following remote path should work:

```
accDB = "\\\\Path\\To\\Network\\Drive\\Access\\Database.accdb"

conn <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=", accDB))
```

Also, a properly mapped local drive that maps to UNC should work:

```
accDB = "Z:\\Mapped\\Path\\To\\Network\\Drive\\Access\\Database.accdb"

conn <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=", accDB))
```

Comment: I was actually able to get it to work with forward slashes (/).  No need to escape anything

Comment: Correct. You can do either.