# Access ACCDB, R Stuido 64bit connection error

Tags: database, ms-access, rodbc

I am new to R and am trying to bring in data from an Access Database which is hosted on a shared network drive.

I'm running 64Bit Windows 7 and am using a 64bit version of R Studio. The Microsoft Access Database Engine has been installed on my machine and under User DSN (From the ODBC Data Source Administrator, under control panel) I can see MS Access Database.

I followed the instructions from this excellent post: [ODBC connect from R to Access DB .accdb file on Network Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515907/odbc-connect-from-r-to-access-db-accdb-file-on-network-drive)

The first part of the code works a charm: `accDB = "\\\\wspfilukfarn\\GBZFSWF1_PUBLIC\\DPT\\DPT_SHARED_LOOKUP_BE.accdb"`

The problem I run into is with the second part, running this code: `conn <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=", accDB))` gives me the following error:

> Warning messages: 1: In odbcDriverConnect(paste0("Driver={Microsoft
>   Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=",  :   [RODBC] ERROR: state
>   IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source
>   name not found and no default driver specified 2: In
>   odbcDriverConnect(paste0("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,
>   *.accdb)};DBQ=",  :   ODBC connection failed

I've read through numerous posts on here with people that have similar issues to me, but none of the solutions put forwards seem to move me any closer.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, at this point I have been struggling for two days on this.

**Final note, I do not have admin access, so will not be able to install any new drivers myself.**